# How should I parse "...many of them efforts..."?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I first saw this question on another forum. (I didn't write the question originally on that forum. )The answer provided there didn't seem complete or understandable to me, so I thought I would ask here.

Specifically, I'm unsure of the meaning of the phrase in bold. I understand the literal meaning of *many of them*, but how does "efforts" go together with this phrase?

> "So while some traditional trades - malster and blacksmith - had declined or vanished, they had been replaced by others, **many of them efforts** New Agey, Back-to-the-Land, and Save-the-Planet in nature." -- G.M.Malliet - Wicked autumn

Larger context:

> The Internet had aided this transformation by allowing villagers ... to set up shop as potters and booksellers ... and sell online what goods they could not sell in their stores. ... Most of all, objects from Awena Owen's Goddessspell flew off the shelves. So to speak.
>
> So while some traditional trades—malster and blacksmith, saddler and wheelwright—had declined or vanished, they had been replaced by others, many of them efforts New Agey, Back-to-the-Land, and Save-the-Planet in nature. The villagers quickly had discovered that city dwellers would pay almost any price for a product labelled "organic" or "handmade."

Comment: No offense, but The spelling of "vanishe" and "BAck-to-Land" made me doubt the authenticity of the quoted passage.

Comment: Yea I detected the spelling of "vanishe", but kept it as it is as it was the same thing I quoted.

Comment: A quick look at the passage on Google Books seems to indicate that the misspellings are not the fault of the author but that of whoever first posted the question. That being said, what about that phrase confuses you? There are several different ways to approach the question depending on what you're looking for.

Comment: Well I understand the meaning of "many of them". I believe it's usage here mean the normal literal meaning. Then the "efforts" confuses me. Please explain the meaning, and their usage.

Comment: Hmm. Alright. I edited your question a little to make it clearer what you are asking. (Or at least as I understand it.) I also fixed the errors in the quote since they aren't really important to your question, and they were not present in the original text. If my edit was incorrect, please do your own edit to bring it more in line with what you were asking.

Comment: Man_From_India, what is meant by the word "*malster*"?

Answer (score 4):

*Efforts* and *many of them* refer to *others*, which in turns refers back to *trades*. One could more simply write out the meaning as

> So while some trades… had declined or vanished, they had been replaced by others, many of which were New Agey… in nature.

or more explicitly as

> So while some trades… had declined or vanished, those trades had been replaced by others. Many of these other efforts were New Agey… in nature.

Comment: Your last sentence *"Many of these other efforts were New Agey… in nature."* seems as if a hint that a sentence such as *"Many of them efforts New Agey, Back-to-the-Land, and Save-the-Planet in nature,"* is good English (or at least acceptable).

Comment: Thanks. But I'm really curious about the style of writing of the author. For example, I found this sentence in an excerpt from the same book, *She stood, feet solidly planted, a vital, comely, and charismatic ﬁgure who, although essentially otherworldly, managed to operate her New Age gift shop on a large proﬁt margin.* I'm not sure how many ellipses were made, because it looks like a run-on sentence to me.

Comment: @DamkerngT. In that sentence, I would say there is no ellipsis at work, just an unusually long string of apposition all referring back to *she*.

Comment: Actually, upon consideration, I don't think ellipsis is at work in the original; I removed the reference to it as it will confuse matters.

Comment: I still couldn't parse that *She stood ...* sentence, and it might deserve to be another question on its own. If possible, you can help me parse it there: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/please-help-me-parse-this-sentence.

Comment: It's getting clearer now, but not completely. "many of them efforts" = "some of those efforts (are)". I think "are" is omitted intentionally for, might be, the style. Am I right? Another doubt is before "effort", when it's used like this, we should place a possessive form, but I doubt "many of them" conveys a "nominal form", rather a "possessive form". Please explain this.

Comment: As a way to avoid rewriting the sentence, consider "many of them were efforts that were ... ." I think this was a stylistic choice, and (if I had to guess), I'd guess that it originally was even more awkwardly phrased at first, but edited down to the puzzling printed result.

Comment: "many of them" + "effort" usage is not not at all clear.

Comment: The sentence as written originally was in general poorly constructed.  Choster's analysis is correct to me - I would guess that the author was attempting to make a stylistic construction similar to many literary sources (and failed).  The phrase @DamkerngT. quoted is constructed much better and uses similar style.

Answer (score 0):

The more correct versions would be

> Many of **the** other efforts **being**....
>
> Many of **these** other efforts **being**.....
>
> Many of **those** other efforts **being**....